# number systems in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried to initiate a command that the bot will count number systems. When I tried to run the command with the number system it did not get a response to discord. Normally, when I tried print, the console replied.

```
@client.command()
async def bin_dec(ctx,a):
   t=int(a,2)
   await ctx.send("Sum: ",t)
```

Comment: Where did you define `a`?

Comment: yes I have declared and still not sending a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in the string.

When `printing` this isn't necessary because `print` can  take multiple arguments & print all of them, but `ctx.send` only takes 1, being the string to send (and some optional positional arguments but that's not relevant here).

Any way of putting an `int` in a `string` works, for example you can use `str.format()`:

```py
await ctx.send("Sum: {}".format(t))
```